# How to find the shortest path of a weighted tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree

I have a weighted tree which looks like (weights are in brackets)

```
          A1
        /   \
     B1(3)  B2(2)
     /   \  /  \
   C1(1) C2(3) C3(4)
   /   \ /  \  /  \
 D1(8) D2(7) D3(2) D4(5) 
    ......
```

So, each node has two children. And each node shares a child with a neighbour node. A depth of the tree can be very high.

```
3 + 1 + 8 = 12
3 + 1 + 7 = 11
3 + 3 + 7 = 13 ... and so on
```

What is the best way to find the shortest path? As a result I need not a sum of weights but a full path (lets say A1-B2-C3-D3).

I will be more than happy if you could reference me to the right algorithm.. Or provide java/pseudo code solution.

Thank you!

## Update

I am looking for a full path from top to bottom

Comment: Are you looking for shortest path between any two vertices or of some starting from the root?

Comment: This is not a tree. A tree should only have one path between any two vertices. This is basically a 2D-grid.

Answer (score 5):

This may be a natural Dynamic Programming (DP) problem due to the child sharing property. I suggest using a bottom-up DP algorithm to solve this problem.

1. Define the state of each node as SP(n), which means shortest path from that node. We could notice that the SP(n) is only dependent on the SP(c), where c is child of n. And because of the child sharing property, the SP(n) may be reused by n's parents.
2. The state transformation equation is listed as below:

   > SP(n) = min {for every c of n's children | SP(c) + weight(c)}

As for implementation, we scan bottom-up from leaves to compute the SP(n) until we reach the root. And the time cost is O(n) since we compute it in one run.

Comment: I want to add the rationale for using a bottom-up approach. Take any leaf `l`, its ancestor `T` can travel to either `l` or to `l`'s sibling. If `T` is part of the shortest route, then its child leaf with the least weight (either `l` or `l`'s sibling) will also be part of the shortest route. You eliminate half of the leafs as possibilities by doing that step alone.

Comment: Do you have any reference or pseudo code for this, from which I can draw up the code? Its still tough for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [Alpha-beta-pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning). This algorithm basically removes part of the search tree as soon as they are known to be obsolete, i.e. a shorter path to the same position is already known.